# How do I add the outputs of a loop?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, output

So in this program, I have to do multiplication in a very tedious fashion and for the second loop, the for loop, I'm multiplying one variable by 2 and the output is the product of that multiplication I am wondering how I could go about taking those output values and adding them together. The code and output of the code are below

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Time to do some Martian Math" << endl;
    // variables for math
    int righthandnum;
    int lefthandnum;

    cout << "Please enter two numbers" << endl;
    // get values to do the martian math
    cin >> lefthandnum;
    cin >> righthandnum;

    //while loop for right hand number
    int i = 0;
    while (righthandnum >= 1 ) {
        //cout << righthandnum << endl;
        //if to find out if any values are odd
        if (righthandnum % 2 == 0) {
            i -= 1;
        }
        righthandnum = righthandnum / 2;
        i++;
    }
    int num;
    for (num = 1; num <= i; num++) {
        lefthandnum = lefthandnum * 2;
        
        //lefthandnum + lefthandnum;
        cout << lefthandnum  << endl;
    }

    
    return 0;
}
```

```
The output is 
Time to do some Martian Math
Please enter two numbers
50
30
100
200
400
800
```

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: You know how to add to a variable, so what is stopping you from solving this?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for but maybe a stack or an array might help you

with the array (the easy way), you make a list of N size for the data as an example:

```
int values[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
std::cin>>values[i];
}
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
std::cout<<"List element "<<i<<": "<<values[i]<<std::endl;
}
```

while the stack as I've used it it's a bit more complex and requires pointers.
this is a video (sorry it's in Spanish): https://youtu.be/joAw2jWgZqA

Comment: if you want to use the array to add the numbers do:
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
sum = sum + values[i];
}